# How did the Robot learn where Alpha Centauri is?

Tags: lost-in-space-2018

In Season 2 Episode 10, nobody knows where they are or how to get to Alpha Centauri.  Their only breadcrumb is a radio signature that they assume is from a Jupiter.  However, ...

> the radio signature is actually that of the lost Fortuna mission.  Thus, when the Robot opens a rift to that location, the kids get sidetracked and stranded on the Robot's origin planet for awhile.

Later, in Season 3 Episode 4, ...

> after the kids show up to save the parents from SAR, the Robot now can open a rift directly to Alpha Centarui, without any explanation of how he knows that.

How did the Robot gain that knowledge?

> From Scarecrow?  If so, why was SAR unable to gain that same knowledge from Scarecrow?

Comment: Anyone?   Anyone?  Not even a guess?